# Writing a column total to any location

Tags: excel, vba

**This code just sum the values to the bottom of each column, but I want the sum of those values to the last column**

[image]

```
Sub Sum_Last_Row()

Dim LastColumn As Long


LastColumn = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row



Range("A" & LastColumn + 1 & ":D" & LastColumn + 1).Formula = "=SUM(A2:A" & LastColumn & ")"


End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried your formula out in Excel itself first? Wouldn't you first want a plan with a working formula before you turn to VBA? Think about, **where** exactly you want to put **what** formula.

Comment: `Range("E2:E" & LastColumn).Formula = "=SUM(A2:D2)"`

Comment: I'm creating a macro to sum all the rows and put them the total in the last column. The code that is above show the sum but at the bottom of each column.

Answer (score 0):

The function below can be used in your code as well as a UDF called from the worksheet. For either use, save it to a standard code module in your VBA Project.

```
Function SumColumn(Rng As Range, _
                   Optional ByVal FirstRow As Long = 1) As Double

    Dim SumRng As Range
    Dim C As Long

    C = Rng.Column
    FirstRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(FirstRow, 1)
    With Rng.Worksheet
        ' define the range by [First cell], [Last cell]
        Set SumRng = .Range(.Cells(FirstRow, C), _
                            .Cells(.Rows.Count, C).End(xlUp))
    End With
    SumColumn = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(SumRng)
End Function
```

The function takes two parameters, the second one, *FirstRow*, is optional. If it's omitted the function will sum everything in the column, starting with row 1 to the end of the column. If `FirstRow` is a number smaller than the last used row the function will return a sum taken from the specified `FirstRow` to the last used row. A number smaller than 1 will be converted to 1. A number larger than the last used row will return the value found in the last used row.

The first parameter is a range. When the function is called from code that could be a single cell or a huge, multi-column range. The function will use the first column of either. The same is true when the function is called from a worksheet. However, the definition of of the range determines when Excel will update the function result. Both `=SumColumn(A1)` and `=SumColumn(A:A)` will return the same result, as will `SumColumn(A:D)`, but the first version will be recalculated automatically only when there is a change in A1 whereas the last one will update whenever there is a change anywhere in columns A:D. Obviously this is an overkill because only changes in column A can affect the total produced by the function. Doing unnecessary calculations will slow down the worksheet.

Here are some samples of UDF calls from the worksheet. They can be placed in any cell, on any sheet, except those included in the SumRange because that will lead to a circular reference error.

```
=SumColumn(D:D,4)        ' start summing from row 4
=SumColumn($D:$D,4)      ' absolute referencing for copying to other columns
=SumColumn(D:D)          ' start summing in row 1
```

Examples of calls from code:-

```
' replace column IDs with column numbers if you wish
Cells(1, "A").Value = SumColumn(Columns("D"), 2)
Debug.Print SumColumn(Columns("D"), 2)
Sheet1.Cells(1, "A").Value = SumColumn(Sheet2.Columns("D"), 2)
Set Rng = Range("D8:AB17")
' the function will sum column D from row 3:-
Sheet1.Cells(1, 10).Value = SumColumn(Rng, 3)
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, it was very helpful Variatus

Comment: I'm glad my effort helped you. However, if you did use my code please do "Select" the answer as a guide to others who might follow you with a similar problem. Thank you.